# ternary operator is not listening to local state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, ternary

I want my className to change when I hover over my div. If i console log the state it changes from true to false depending on the position of the mouse. When I try to use it with a ternary operator, it always sets itself to false?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function NavigationBar() {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState({hover: false})

  const noHovering = 'flex flex-row bg-white'
  const hovering = 'flex flex-row bg-black'
  return (
  <div className='h-screen max-h-screen w-1/6 float-left shadow-2xl flex flex-col' style={{backgroundColor: '#2b2b2b'}}>
    <div className='h-20 flex justify-center items-center' style={{backgroundColor:'#202020'}}>
      <h1 className='text-white items-center font-hairline tracking-widest text-lg'>{hover === true ? "NOT WOKRING" : 'PREVENTION ADMIN'}</h1>
    </div>
    <div className='pl-4 h-full flex flex-col justify-around'>
      <div className= {hover ? hovering : noHovering} onMouseOver={() => setHover({hover:true})} onMouseLeave={() => setHover({hover:false})}>
        <img src={require('../../images/analysis-gray.png')} alt='analysis' className='mr-5 w-6'/> 
        <h5 className='antialiased' style={{color:'#c8c8c8'}} >Insights</h5>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think you are initialising your state in a wrong way. Try this - `const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary operator always returns true because you're checking the instance `hover` that is a truthy value.

Based on how you defined your state, you have to check the field `hover` with `hover.hover`

```js
    const [hover, setHover] = useState({hover: false})
    <div 
     className= {hover.hover ? hovering : noHovering} 
     onMouseOver={() => setHover({hover:true})} 
     onMouseLeave={() => setHover({hover:false})}>
    ..
    </div>
```

Or, alternatively switch to a boolean value which makes things simpler:

```
    const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)
    <div 
     className= {hover ? hovering : noHovering} 
     onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)} 
     onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
    ..
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`hover ? ...` always returns `true` because it is an object `{ hover: false }`, you don't need an object here, change your state to:

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false)
```

and when you want to set `hover`:

```
setHover(true)
// Or
setHover(false)
```

If you want to keep it as an object, just change your condition to:

```
hover.hover ? hovering : noHovering
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a need of having the `hover` state as an object and then reading the property inside it. You can just do it like this:-

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
const noHovering = 'flex flex-row bg-white'
const hovering = 'flex flex-row bg-black'

<div 
 className= {hover? hovering : noHovering} 
 onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)} 
 onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}>
..
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current state shape, just use a [destructured assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract `hover` property:

```
//     v       v  extract hover property from state 
const [{ hover }, setHover] = useState({hover: false})
```